# Cache MLlib model on SparkJobServer

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

Can somebody tell me how I can persist namedObjects on a SparkServer Context? I know there is a possibility for this but I haven't found the solution yet.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What version of Job Server / Spark do you use?

Comment: JobServer: 0.6.1/ 
Spark: 1.5.0/ Scala: 2.10.4

Answer (score 0):

This is only recently merged. See https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/pull/350

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw this one but it seems that the version with NamedObjectSupport is still not released. At least for me, `NamedObjectSupport is not a member of package spark.jobserver` yet.